# Custom actions in MSI setup not working properly when upgrade to VS2010

Tags: visual-studio-2010, mfc, visual-studio-2005, windows-installer

I had a setup which was built using vs2005 works fine.
It has custom action install and uninstall actions. They works fine in vs2005.
I converted this to vs2010. 
Now when I try to upgrade my application using newly build setup it doesn't work as intended.
Intended way.

1. Run customActionInstall and save registry entries to a file
2. Do the uninstallation of previous version
3. Install new version
4. Run customActionInstall and restore registry back.

what could have go wrong?

Comment: You don't say what's actually going wrong. Either way you might want to consider migrating to Wix, it provides much clearer control over what's happenning.

Comment: Did you link you custom actions statically? Custom action implementation could require a DLL, Visual C++ runtime for example, which is not installed.

Comment: As I read it says that in VS2010 they have changed the execute sequence. In vs2005 when we do a upgrade first they remove all the stuffs and install back the new version. But in vs2010 it doesn't call uninstall, just replace the files based on version numbers.

Answer (score 1):

That will not work with VS 2010 because of what Thuiya says. In VS 2005 your custom action would run before the older product was uninstalled and it would save the registry keys. Now your custom action runs too late, after the upgrade has finished.

Actually, I believe that you might not need to save the keys anyway. As long as your setup hasn't changed drastically, the upgrade behaves like an update patch that might not replace the entries, that's a vague possibility, but from your comment maybe it doesn't work.  So VS 2010 won't let you do what you want. Other tools will because they let you change when your custom action runs